# TSQL- Run stored procedure if backup data is less than specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Some back-story. We have a test environment that houses test data. Every night, a job copies over database backups from production and restores them to test. Not so often, we'll have a database backup that is over a few days old from someone having a application open.

I'm looking to run a stored procedure that inserts data into a table, but only when the last database backup time is less than a few days old and if it isn't, send out an email to a user. I'd want this to be used as a scheduled job in SQL Server. Here's a query I've found from the web and have edited it to our liking:

```
WITH RecentBackup
AS
(  
SELECT sdb.Name AS DatabaseName,
bus.backup_finish_date AS LastBackUpTime,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sdb.Name ORDER BY bus.backup_finish_date DESC) AS     1RowNum
FROM sys.sysdatabases sdb
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus ON bus.database_name = sdb.name
GROUP BY sdb.Name, bus.backup_finish_date
)

SELECT DatabaseName, LastBackUpTime
      ,CASE
       WHEN CAST(LastBackUpTime AS DATE) >= GETDATE() - 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END AS GoodBackup
  FROM RecentBackup 
 WHERE RowNum = 1
```

If all of the rows show GoodBackup = 1, I want the stored procedure to run, if GoodBackup = 0 on any of the rows, then I want the job to fail.

Here's some example data:

```
DatabaseName    LastBackUpTime              GoodBackup
Database1       2014-08-16 22:00:45.000     1
Database2       2014-08-14 22:30:20.000     0
Database3       2014-08-16 21:15:07.000     1
Database4       2014-08-16 21:25:03.000     1
Database5       2014-08-16 21:30:54.000     1
Database6       2014-08-16 21:00:03.000     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be over simplifying this but would something similar to this work?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT GoodBackUp FROM
                RecentBackup
                WHERE GoodBackUp = 1
            )

BEGIN
EXEC usp_Success_proc
END
ELSE
BEGIN
EXEC usp_Issue_email
END
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Since you were the first one to answer, I'll mark this one as the answer. Both solutions worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Store the results from your query in #results and then

```
IF ( EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #results WHERE GoodBackup = 0) )
     EXEC sp_my_stored_proc
ELSE
     RAISEERROR('Old backup', 11, 0)
```

You could also integrate your code into the pattern instead of relying on a temporary table.